# iDangerous Swiper – Multiple Instances

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add multiple instances of the iDangerous Swiper on a single page jquery mobile site. It seems that after a page is changed using Ajax the swiper's pagination and order get out of whack. Also it seems to lose track of the item count. So, say there's 6 divs in the swiper, you change to another page and return, the pagination will show 8 items.

By default the swiper will not work at all but I managed to find hack by adding this after each "data-role='page'" element:

```
<script>
        $("#pagename").on('pageshow', function(){
            $('#pagename .swiper-container').each(function(){
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-one', {pagination : '.pagination-one', createPagination: true  ,loop:true, grabCursor: true});
            });
        });
</script>
```

How can I get this working? I need 6 different swipers on a single page jquery site.

I thinking I need to do some kind of refresh after the page transition. Something that will remove all other instances of the Swiper.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Please Try Following Code its may be helpful to you......

```
<div class="swiper-container s1">
  ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-container s2">
  ...
</div>
<div class="swiper-container s3">
  ...
</div>
```

In script..

```
<script>
    var swiper1 = new Swiper('.s1', { /* Options here */ })
    var swiper2 = new Swiper('.s2', { /* Options here */ })
    var swiper3 = new Swiper('.s3', { /* Options here */ })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the object into the constructor, like this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper($(this)[0], {
    pagination : '.pagination-one', 
    createPagination: true,
    loop:true, 
    grabCursor: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a demo in the downloaded zip for this from swiper Version 3.3.1. It´s called 24-multiple-swipers.html.

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
...
...
<div class="swiper-container swiper2">
...
...
<div class="swiper-container swiper3">
...
...
```

and the JS:

```
<script>
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination2',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
});
var swiper3 = new Swiper('.swiper3', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination3',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
});
</script>
```